# How to rename commands (print, os.<...>) in python?

Tags: python, command

How can you rename functions in python, like renaming `print` to something like `say`?

Things like little changes in python's code that you could potentially make into a module (for something like an addon pack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to rename print but this is how I would do it.

For python 3.X:

```
myvar = "Hello World"
say = print

say (myvar)
```

my example for Python 3.X does not seam to be viable for Python 2.X unless anyone else knows a way similar to my example. Otherwise here is way you can do for Python 2.X

```
myvar = "Hello World"

def printFun(stuff):
    print(stuff)

say = printFun

say (myvar) # note that like python 3 you must put this in ()
```

Anytime you want to "rename" a function all you need to do is assign that function to a variable and then use that variable as the function.

Edit: On a related note you can also import the python 3 function to python 2:

```
# this is good to use in 2.X to help future proof your code. 
# for at least the print statement
from __future__ import print_function 

myvar = 'Hello World'
say = print

say (myvar)
```

Comment: You don't need parentheses around `print`.

Comment: Invalid syntax error, might be the python version. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille He's using Python 3

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was showing up as an error for a sec in my IDE but looks like it works fine without the parentheses

Comment: @JilkOwez: you must be using Python 2, where `print` is a statement. In Python 3, it's a normal function.

Comment: If this answers your question make sure to select the check mark next to the post.

Comment: @SierrMountainTech Its after 10 mins, I will check it out.

Comment: Just installing 3.6 now, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: I added a method for python 2.X if you need that also. Sometimes you must use an older version of python if a python package you need is not available yet for 3.X

Comment: @SierrMountainTech Yeah, I just installed python 3.6, Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @eryksun True but the question was not just for print. They were asking about functions as well. That being said thanks for bringing it up. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @SierrMountainTech I was referring to basic commands in python but a mod deleted where I said commands. Thanks for the added code though :P!

Comment: @Jilk Owez: I can see how that would cause some confusion.